# bash : read a line from a file and interpret this line

Tags: bash

I have a file with this line for example :

```
${blue}*Passed*${NC}: check the command line ...
```

I can read in bash this line :

```
red='\e[41m'
blue='\e[1;34m'
purple='\e[1;31m'
NC='\e[0m' # No Color

 while read line
 do
      echo -e $line
 done < test_contest
```

But the output is like this :

> ${blue}*Passed*${NC}: check the command line ...

there is no color, can bash interpret this line to output color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
echo -e $line
```

With:

```
eval echo -e \"$line\"
```